# Mostrando o valor de ReadProcessMemory C++

Tags: c++, label

uma vez que eu utilizei  a função abaixo:

```
  BOOL readyProcessMe = ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPCVOID)memory, &value, 4, 0);
```

Como posso eu mostrar o valor correto em uma label?

Comment: Parece que o Valor estará na variável value, após a função ser chamada, caso o retorno do BOOL seja TRUE

Comment: sim. isso eu sei. agora quero saber como mostrar .pq to fazendo LPCWSTR(value) em um messagebox mas vem vazio sem nada :(

Comment: Ao debugar aí, o valor da variável value está preenchido aí? Então acrescente à pergunta o código que chama o messagebox, para vermos o que há.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz `LPCWSTR(value)` você esta a variável `value` como um ponteiro, e portanto passa a referenciar um endereço de memória.

Você tem que converter `value`, que deve ser um inteiro de 32 bits, para uma string, por exemplo, utilizando a função `sprintf`, e então colocar esta string no label.